# How do I remap caps to control on osx with multiple keyboards attached?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-layout

My office does pairing so we have 2 keyboards, mice, and monitors per computer.  Many people like to remap `caps lock` to `control`, but changing the setting for it in `OSX` only changes one of the keyboards.  Is there a trick to get `OSX` to change the settings for all the keyboards attached?

Comment: You should be able to select the keyboard to apply these settings to in the preference pane where you change the modifier key mappings. Just repeat for both.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I can't find a place to choose between keyboards.